# VHDL Multiplication

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I am trying to multiply x by 5/7 in this VHDL code. After some tweaking, as to understand how the process in VHDL works, as seen in the simulation diagram, I could not get the output y to go to "1111111111" whenever x > X"2", it continues to change values after every change in x. (For a minimal reproducible problem).
Here's the modified code. This should be an easy problem, but I just can't get the hang of VHDL. The other version of the same problem is located at [Multiplication in VHDL by a fraction](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/663949/multiplication-in-vhdl-by-a-fraction/)
This code causes Vivado to crash now whenever I run behavioral simulation.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;

entity lab47 is
    Port ( x : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           y : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0));
end lab47;

architecture rtl of lab47 is

constant cnst1 : std_logic_vector(19 downto 0) := "10110110110110110111";

signal cnst2 : std_logic_vector(27 downto 0);


begin

  process(x)
  begin

     cnst2 <= unsigned(x) * unsigned(cnst1);
     
     --y <= cnst2(27 downto 18);

     if (x >= "00000000" and x < X"2") then y <= "000000000" & cnst2(18);
     else y <= "1111111111";
     end if;     
    
     end process;

end rtl;
```

The simulation code

```
library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity test_bench is
-- Port();
end test_bench;

architecture simulate of test_bench is

signal  x : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal  y : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0) := (others => '0');

component lab47 is
    Port ( x : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           y : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0));
end component lab47;

begin

dut : lab47 port map (x => x,
                      y => y);


input_gen : process
begin

    x <= "00000000",
         "00000000" after 1ns, 
         "00000001" after 10 ns,
         "00000010" after 20 ns,
         "00000011" after 30 ns,
         "00000100" after 40 ns,
         "00000101" after 50 ns,
         "00000110" after 60 ns,
         "00000111" after 70 ns,
    
         "00001000" after 80 ns,
         "00001001" after 90 ns,
         "00001010" after 100 ns,
         "00001011" after 110 ns,
         "00001100" after 120 ns,
         "00001101" after 130 ns,
         "00001110" after 140 ns,
         "00001111" after 150 ns,
         
         "00010000" after 160 ns,
         "00010001" after 170 ns,
         "00010010" after 180 ns,
         "00010011" after 190 ns,
         "00010100" after 200 ns,
         "00010101" after 210 ns,
         "00010110" after 220 ns,
         "00010111" after 230 ns,
         "00011000" after 240 ns,
         "00011001" after 250 ns,
         "00011010" after 260 ns,
         "00011011" after 270 ns,
         "00011100" after 280 ns,
         "00011101" after 290 ns,
         "00011110" after 300 ns,
         "00011111" after 310 ns;             
        wait;        
    end process;    

end simulate;
```

And the result of the simulation waveform.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: `y` never turning "1111111111" *should* tell you `x >= "00000000" or x < X"2"` is true. (To spoil a learning experience and see more, [edit my former answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/663959/revisions).

Comment: Now this may be more suitable to a Xilinx/Xivado(/ISim?) support forum.

Answer (score 0):

No crash on Vivado v2021.2 and the test just passes 300ns as expected with this new version of your testbench:

[image]

Comment: How can I remove the yellow waveform in the first 10ns of simulation? It seems cnst2 is not updated, do you know how to fix it? @greybeard ?

Comment: @Zzz cnst2(18) should be on the process sensitivity list or, if you don't want to bother with this, use the "all" keyword.